# MomentJS - Showing the wrong time for Pacific Timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I did not write the code involving Moment. But I'm tying to convert it to plain JavaScript.

```js
moment.tz.add("America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT PWT PPT|80 70 70 70|010102301010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010|-261q0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 SgN0 8x10 iy0 5Wp1 1VaX 3dA0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1a00 1fA0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 s10 1Vz0 LB0 1BX0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0|15e6");
console.log('Central Time: ', moment()._d.toString());
console.log('Pacific Time: ', moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles")._d.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
```

I live in the Central Time Zone. As you can see above, MomentJS returns the correct time for the Central Timezone.

However, when I try to get the time in the Pacific Time Zone, it is 5 hours off. I suspect it has to do with the GMT difference, as shown here.

```
GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

I have looked through the documentation and studied this extensively but cannot figure out why the time is 5 hours off.

Comment: `console.log('Central Time: ', moment()._d.toString());` doesn't result in specifically in Central time - it just returns the current time in whatever timezone your computer is set to. In the UK it gives the current time here with `GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`

Comment: I would have thought that Pacific Daylight Time should be GMT-0700 where CDT actually is GMT-0500 [CDT on Timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cdt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key point here is to avoid using the internal `_d` variable.

See [`Moment Internal Properties`](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) for details.

These values will not give the expected result:

> In particular if Moment TimeZone is in use, this property will almost never be the same as the actual value that Moment will output from its public .format() function.

I would suggest using the .toString() or format() functions to output the date value.

You can also use the [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) function to output a date in a given timezone in plain JavaScript.

```js
// Moment
console.log('Moment:');
console.log('Local Time: ', moment().toString());
console.log('Central Time: ', moment().tz("America/Chicago").toString());
console.log('Pacific Time: ', moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").toString());

// Plain JavaScript
let opts = { 
  weekday: 'short', month: 'short', day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
  timeZoneName: 'short' 
}

console.log('\nPlain JS:');
console.log('Local Time: ', new Date().toLocaleString('default', opts));
console.log('Central Time: ', new Date().toLocaleString('default', { ...opts, timeZone: 'America/Chicago' })); 
console.log('Pacific Time: ', new Date().toLocaleString('default', { ...opts, timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed answer. The issue was with using the internal `_d` variable as you mentioned. I was using it because `moment` in the console returns a JavaScript object. I thought `_d` stood for date. ToString though is very clever

Answer (score 1):

Without moment, you can convert your timezone like below

```
// I live in a country with GMT+03:00 timezone
console.log(new Date()) //outputs: Fri Jul 08 2022 15:53:06 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/New_York'})) //outputs: "7/8/2022, 8:53:06 AM"
```

With moment

```
var date = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");
date.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');  // outputs: 5am PDT
```

Further reading

[Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: Than you for your help.